# Ruby Dynamic Nested Namespacing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Given two model that are namespaced as

```
    SomeModule::V1::Api 
    SomeModule::V2::Api
```

I want to make a call in my controller like:

```
    api = SomeModule::V1::Api
```

but have the "V1" portion be a variable, so that I can swap between versions.

Any ideas on how to make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v = 'V1'
"SomeModule::#{v}::Api".constantize
=> SomeModule::V1::Api
```

Example:

```
module SomeModule
  module V1; end
  module V2; end
end

class SomeModule::V1::Api
  def self.foo; 'V1 foo'; end
end

class SomeModule::V2::Api
  def self.foo; 'V2 foo'; end
end

v = 'V1'
puts "SomeModule::#{v}::Api".constantize.foo
=> V1 foo
v = 'V2'
puts "SomeModule::#{v}::Api".constantize.foo
=> V2 foo
```

Comment: awesome. choosing this one over the one below because I am working within Rails and have ActiveSupport. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `#constantize` (which is a part of ActiveSupport), you can do it with Plain Old Ruby:

```
version = "V1"
SomeModule.const_get(version).const_get("Api")
# => SomeModule::V1::Api
```

Comment: +1, although the question was tagged as RoR so I assumed `ActiveSupport` would be acceptable.

Comment: Yeah, I prefer `#constantize` personally, but I've had to do it a few times outside of a Rails context, so I figured I'd offer the option. :)

Comment: This answer is also good too. Definitely useful outside of Rails. Will keep in my backpocket.